# How to dynamically identify whether an element is a variable or a cordinate

Tags: python, parsing

In my app, I am developing an app that has a small scripting feature

My app mainly deals with 2D cordinates

In the scripting feature, I want to make use of dynamic variables

example:

```py
def calc(line: str):
    """
    Super duper complex function that I don't know how I wrote.

    Examples:

    calc add 0,0 0,0 result
    calc sub Var anotherPosVar result
    calc add 0,0 posVar result
    calc add posVar 0,0 result
    calc mul defaultPos 10,10 result
    """
```

[image]

### My question is:

How do I parse that line so that it will give me 2 sets of cordinates and a name(of the variable)

Here is where i am stuck at:

```py
def getcords(line: str) -> tuple[tuple[int, int], tuple[int, int], str]:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        line (str): _description_

    Returns:
        tuple[tuple[int, int], str]: The cords and the name of the cords (to store in M_LOCATIONS)
    """
    # The number/variable parser for the calc command
    # Gives 2 sets of cordinates and the name of the variable to store the result in

    # Get the first number depending on if it is a variable or not
```

I need the parser to figure out whether it is a variable or a static cordinate

If it is a variable, I want it to get the cordinated stored in `M_LOCATIONS`

The structure of `M_LOCATIONS`

```py
M_LOCATIONS: dict[str, tuple[int, int]]: = {

    "pos1": (100, 100),
    "anotherPos": (24, 132)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is a possible solution to your question:

```
def getcords(line: str) -> tuple:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        line (str): _description_

    Returns:
        tuple[tuple[int, int], str]: The cords and the name of the cords (to store in M_LOCATIONS)
    """
    
    # With input: "calc add 2,3 4,5 result" lineList = ['calc', 'add', '2,3', '4,5', 'result']
    lineList = line.split(' ')
    
    variableNameOutput = lineList[-1]   # variableNameOutput = "result"
    Coord1 = [int(i) for i in lineList[-3].split(',')]       # Coord1 = [ 2, 3]
    Coord2 = [int(i) for i in lineList[-2].split(',')]       # Coord2 = [4, 5]
    print(Coord1)
    return (Coord1, Coord2, variableNameOutput)
    
res = getcords("calc add 2,3 4,5 result")
#output ([2, 3], [4, 5], 'result')
# res[0] = [2, 3]
# res[1] = [4, 5]
# res[2] = 'result'
```

I changed your return value type to only tuple.

Comment: See, the thing is, the 2 input cords can also be a string, like
`calc add cord1 cord2 result`
`calc add cord1 10,10 result`
I will edit to question to include this